# Drawing an isosurface in n-dimension

Tags: algorithm, discrete-mathematics, random

This is more of a code agnostic problem.

In discrete space, I need to draw random points along arbitrary implicit polynomials, of arbitrary dimension and arbitrary degree.

I work on it using C++, and I have the Eigen library available (however I doubt that any kind of solver could be used on any degree?). Higher level functions and languages are thus not a solution (MATLAB for example or even Python).

Anyway, my current naive way is to:

- draw a random point in space
- determine the value of the isofunction for this point
- create an adjacency ball of the point
- of all neighbors, determine the closest to the surface
- move the considered point in place of this neighbor. If the point move outside my range, just delete it
- repeat until the isofunction is null

Now, I could see several way to improve. Do not generate a whole adjacency ball each time, but simply draw a line and make a sort of binary search along this line.

Anyway, the method is still very similar at its core.

(on a side note, the isofunction is continuous, however I use some kind of digitization to evaluate whether my point is actually lying on it or not)

My problem with this is that it is pretty low for large n (3+), and that, more importantly, the points will tend to concentrate on certain parts of the isosurface. I use this to generate datasets to evaluate some algorithms, so even if the distribution is not a problem of prime importance, the ability for me to control the quality of the dataset would be interesting.

Is there a better way to distribute random points on an isosurface?